# How to add Data markers in Waterfall chart in Plotly

Tags: r, r-plotly

I am trying to plot waterfall chart with the following code. The only issue I am facing currently is the data marker which is not at the correct place. I want the data marker to be just below the end of each bar.

```
source('./r_files/flatten_HTML.r')
library("plotly")
 dataset <- data.frame(Category = c("Akash Jain","Ankit Jain","Pankaj Jain","Nitin Pandey","Gopal Pandit","Ramnath Agarwal"),
                      TH =  c(-62,-71,-1010,44,-44,200))
#dataset <- data.frame(Category = Values$Category, TH = Values$TH)
#dataset <- as.data.frame(cbind(Values$Category,Values$TH))
dataset$Category = dataset$Category
dataset$TH = dataset$TH
dataset$SortedCategoryLabel <- sapply(dataset$Category, function(x) gsub(" ", " <br> ", x))
dataset$SortedCategory <- factor(dataset$SortedCategoryLabel, levels = dataset$SortedCategoryLabel)
dataset$id <- seq_along(dataset$TH)
dataset$type <- ifelse(dataset$TH > 0, "in",   "out")
dataset$type <- factor(dataset$type, levels = c("out", "in"))
dataset$end <- cumsum(dataset$TH)
dataset$start <- c(0, head(dataset$end, -1))
Hover_Text <- paste(dataset$Category, "= ", dataset$TH, "<br>")
dataset$colors <- ifelse(dataset$type =="out","red","green")
g <- plot_ly(dataset, x = ~SortedCategory, y = ~start, type = 'bar', marker = list(color = 'rgba(1,1,1, 0.0)'), hoverinfo = 'text') %>%
  add_trace(y = dataset$TH , marker = list(color = ~colors), hoverinfo = "text", text = Hover_Text  ) %>%
  layout(title = '',
         xaxis = list(title = ""),
         yaxis = list(title = ""),
         barmode = 'stack',
         margin = list(l = 50, r = 30, b = 50, t = 20),
         showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_annotations(text = dataset$TH,
                  x = dataset$SortedCategoryLabel,
                  y = dataset$end,
                  xref = "dataset$SortedCategoryLabel",
                  yref = "dataset$end",
                  font = list(family = 'Arial',
                              size = 14,
                              color = "black"),
                  showarrow = FALSE)

g
```

Attached the screenshot of the waterfall chart.
So for the first bar, I need the data marker to be just below the end of red bar. Currently it is overlapping with the bar. And similarly for others.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Regards,
Akash[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify `valign` and `height` inside `add_annotations`:

```
vert.align <- c("bottom","top")[as.numeric(dataset$TH>0)+1]

g <- plot_ly(dataset, x = ~SortedCategory, y = ~start, type = 'bar', 
             marker = list(color = 'rgba(1,1,1, 0.0)'), hoverinfo = 'text') %>%
  add_trace(y = dataset$TH , marker = list(color = ~colors), hoverinfo = "text", 
            text = Hover_Text  ) %>%
  layout(title = '',
         xaxis = list(title = ""),
         yaxis = list(title = ""),
         barmode = 'stack',
         margin = list(l = 50, r = 30, b = 50, t = 20),
         showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_annotations(text = dataset$TH,
                  x = dataset$SortedCategoryLabel,
                  y = dataset$end,
                  xref = "x",
                  yref = "y",
                  valign=vert.align, height=40,
                  font = list(family = 'Arial',
                              size = 14,
                              color = "black"),
                  showarrow = FALSE)
g
```

[image]